# Tool to convert accented characters to HTML entities?

Tags: conversion, special-characters, html

Is there a tool (command-line is fine) that can convert accented characters to HTML entities in Ubuntu? Preferably recursively and without also converting html/php tags.

```
e.g.
from: é
to: &#233;
or: &eacute;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recode can convert to HTML entities:

```
$ echo "é" | recode ..html
&eacute;
```

There are a few slightly different HTML transformations available in recode; see `info recode HTML`.

If you want to recode a file or some files, you can use

```
$ recode ..html one_file another_file and so on
```

For recursive action, use the `find` command, e.g.

```
$ find your_directory -type f -name "*.html"
```

The above find command will only show the files. Please make sure that you have found only the right files, not any binaries and not any files in unwanted directories. **It is also a good idea to make a backup or use a copy of your files, not the real files.** If you have found the correct find command, append `-exec your_command {} +`, where your_command is the `recode ..html` from above and the `{}` denotes the file(s) which are given by find to recode:

```
$ find your_directory -type f -name "*.html" -exec recode ..html {} +
```

But wait a moment, there's one big caveat: `recode ..html` assumes that your input files are in the same character set (encoding) that you are using on the command line. If all of your files use the "modern" UTF-8, it will work fine, because Ubuntu used UTF-8 from the standard. But if some of your files use the older ISO-8859-1 or other charsets, it will be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Ya I ran a rename command to get rid of all the spaces in the files with `rename 's/\ /_/g' *` and then `for i in *.php; do iconv --from-code=ISO-8859-15 --to-code=UTF-8 $i > $i.iconv; mv $i.iconv $i; done` to convert to UTF-8. Problem with that program is that it does every character imaginable, including html and php tags.

Comment: You didn't need to rename the files. You can use double quotes around your variable values, i.e. `"$i"`. These double quotes make sure that your variable values are not split.

Answer (score 0):

probably sed. Tutorial here

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6

for yours example, maybe command

```
sed s/"é"/"\&#233"/g < oldfile > newfile
```

( repair me if im wrong, havent seen sed for a while )

### GUI

probably default installed gedit, ctrl+H

Comment: I'm aware of those tools but I need to convert hundreds of files (so gedit is out) and I need to convert all accented characters (and there are a lot of those).

Comment: if you need to convert hundreds of files, you use that sed with find, maybe like this 

find /folder_where_you_have_files -mindepth 0 -name *.html -exec sed s/"é"/"\&#233"/g < {} > {}.new \;

sed can read instructions from file, so you can replace all char at once. Im not sure that i typed command exactly right, will try on some examples and post if something changes

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source of http://www.text-symbols.com/tools/escape-chars/

Take that javascript, execute it in a js environment that can do some IO (node.js) and just use `find -exec` to find all files to convert and execute your node-based converter on all the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Denwerko suggestion on sed use, I wrote a well documented easily readable open-source bash script that converts accented letters in HTML entities. You can find it here: http://www.lugato.co.uk/silvio_dwl.html
Enjoy it! ;)

Comment: The link for the solution is broken.

Answer (score 0):

There are cases when you want to generate entities for accented characters (à ,è, ì, ò, ù, ...) but want to preserve HTML code (so do not excape "<" and ">" and avoid escaping already escaped entities. In those cases, you can use this code: $string = str_replace(array("<", ">"), array("<", ">"), htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8', FALSE)); This code is compatible with PHP >= 5.2.3

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624909/how-to-convert-accented-chars-to-html-in-php#comment58948867_17625068))